# SQL Data Query from Linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a database called `StandardSoftware` with tables `SoftwareName` and `SoftwareType`.

I have another linked server called `InstalledApplication` with a table `ApplicationName`.

I want to get the software type from the linked server.

How do I achieve it?

Below is the query I used but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (LinkedServer, 'SELECT SoftwareType., ApplicationName
                               FROM Computers, StandardSoftware.dbo.standard_software');
```

Comment: Please read how to write a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you write your question properly more chances to get answer.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged